# How to show this: $\sum_{k=2}^{n}\frac{\ln{k}}{k^2}\approx \ln{n}\cdot\left(\zeta_{n}{(2)}-\frac{\pi^2}{6}\right)+C$

Tags: summation, approximation

> **Show  that:**
>   $$\sum_{k=2}^{n}\dfrac{\ln{k}}{k^2}\approx \ln{n}\cdot\left(\zeta_{n}{(2)}-\dfrac{\pi^2}{6}\right)+C,n\to\infty$$
>   where
>   $$\zeta_{n}{(k)}=\sum_{j=1}^{n}\dfrac{1}{j^k}$$and $C$ is real constant.

I know this
$$\zeta{(x)}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{n^x}$$
$$\Longrightarrow \zeta'{(x)}=-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{\ln{n}}{n^x}$$
let $x=2$,then we have
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{\ln{n}}{n^2}=\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\dfrac{\ln{n}}{n^2}=-\zeta'{(2)}$$
But for this approximation,I can't prove it.

Thank you very much

Comment: $\zeta{(2)} = \pi^2/6$. It looks like you have to take the sum of the series minus the n first terms to achieve the result

Comment: Yes.@T_O,I know this,Thank you

Comment: Don't mind my obvious suggestion, I didn't read it with enough attention :)

Comment: if it's the approximation you want, did you try Euler-Maclaurin formula?

Comment: I don't have an answer. Did you try any method related to mean value theorem? The resulting formula looks like it

Comment: @wonghang,mean value theorem? I can't looks linke it?can you explain?Thank you

Comment: To relate $\zeta'(x)$ and $\zeta(x)$ and something like $f(b)-f(a)=f'(c)(b-a)$ for some $c \in (a,b)$. Imagine $\ln(n)$ is $f'(c)$, $\zeta_n(2) - \zeta(2)$ is $b-a$.

Comment: Try something with http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel's_summation_formula. I don't have time, but I think this is right way.

Comment: $\zeta'(2)$ does have a closed form expression in terms of the Glaisher–Kinkelin constant.

Answer (score 4):

Rewriting the sums a bit, you're asking how to show that

$$
\sum_{k=2}^{\infty} \frac{\ln k}{k^2} - \sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty} \frac{\ln k}{k^2} \approx -\ln n \sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k^2} + C.
$$

Looking at this one might guess that we'll probably have $C = \sum_{k=2}^{\infty} \frac{\ln k}{k^2}$, so we would just need to prove that

$$
\sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty} \frac{\ln k}{k^2} \approx \ln n \sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k^2}. \tag{1}
$$

The argument you would use depends on what exactly you mean by $\approx$.  For example, to leading order

$$
\sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty} \frac{\ln k}{k^2} \approx \int_n^\infty \frac{\ln x}{x^2}\,dx = \frac{\ln n + 1}{n} \approx \frac{\ln n}{n}
$$

and

$$
\sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k^2} \approx \int_n^\infty \frac{dx}{x^2} = \frac{1}{n},
$$

so we have a proof of $(1)$ in this sense.

Comment: I'm not sure what the downvoter has an issue with, but if you're seeking a more rigorous statement of the result then this method will yield that $$\sum_{k=2}^{n}\dfrac{\ln{k}}{k^2} =  C + \ln{n}\cdot\left(\zeta_{n}{(2)}-\dfrac{\pi^2}{6}\right) + \epsilon_n,$$ where $C = \sum_{k=2}^{\infty} \frac{\ln k}{k^2}$ and $$\epsilon_n = o\left(\ln{n}\cdot\left(\zeta_{n}{(2)}-\dfrac{\pi^2}{6}\right)\right)$$ as $n \to \infty$.

Comment: it's not me,But maybe you solution some wrong,Thank you for you solution

Comment: I don't see an error in it, at least :)